# How much protection would a motorcycle jacket provide in a low speed, ebike accident?

Tags: safety, electric-bike, clothes, accidents, protection

How much protection would a motorcycle jacket with CE certified body armor provide in a sub 20mph/32kmh, ebike accident? I'm particularly interested in the following scenarios:

1. A car running a stop sign and hitting me from the side, while both the car and I are at sub 20mph speeds.
2. Falling off the ebike at sub 20mph speeds. This might be due to sudden braking or unexpected obstacles.

In these scenarios, would my likelihood and/or severity of injury be significantly reduced by wearing a motorcycle jacket? This is unclear to me because motorcycle gear is meant to provide protection in different, higher speed scenarios.

I recognize that the best way to keep safe is to avoid these scenarios. However,
I've experienced both of these scenarios on non-electric bikes, despite my best efforts to ride defensively, use dedicated bike lanes, avoid car traffic, use daytime lights, and more.

Thank you in advanced for your advice!

P.S. I wear a good helmet with a 5 star rating from Virginia Tech's bike helmet testing.

Comment: I don't think this would prevent you from one of the most common injuries suffered from cycling, broken collarbones, etc... certainly lower risk of abrasions but I think the significantly higher speeds on motorbikes are a different profile, that's why back protection etc is applied, there.

Answer (score 2):

I think your question is difficult to answer, not least because there is a wide variety of motorcycle clothing.
In the minimum variant, a motorcycle jacket will protect against abrasive injuries, that come from sliding over the road. This is achieved by abrasion-resistant materials such as Leather or selected synthetic fibers, sometimes even Kevlar is used.
A second stage is adding protective pads. These are designed to spread the energy of an impact to a wider area, and are typically present at the elbows, shoulders, and the back, thus protecting those parts of the body that are most likely to be hit, which happens mostly by falling.
The spreading of the energy serves to reduce the force in a small area, at the cost of affecting a wider area, which very often makes the difference between a broken bone and a large bruise.
The third stage, if you will, is protective pads made from gels that are flexible under normal conditions and become rigid when a sudden force is applied.
All this protection has a price, though, and that is reduced agility. Not only is this kind of equipment heavy and it gets hot quickly, it's also quite stiff. Keep in mind that motorbikers do a lot less work on their machine than bicycle riders do, so the ventilation issue is no small one.
Personally, if you are concerned about accidents, you need to find the tradeoff that gives you enough of a feeling of safety without hindering you too much.

Comment: In fact, due to experiencing strong "wind" conditions, motorcycle riders can suffer from cold in weather that would be wonderful for cyclists (say 15-18C).  Leathers would be suffocatingly hot for anyone working harder than the equivalent of a brisk walk, and sweating in them won't be fun.

Answer (score 1):

I used to ride motorcycles and I'd say the point of a jacket is just abrasion protection.  That's a big deal cause in a high speed crash you can easily wear thru clothes (even some leather) and skin all the way to the bone.

The helmet and spine protector are what keep you from dying or being paralyzed.  Under 20 mph those are probably a lot less important but you can still die.

I think you'd be ok with that good helmet and a willingness to heal a few abrasions and/or broken bones.  Maybe wear leather or look for a motorcycle jacket with super light armor if abrasions scare you (they scare me).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you speak about the "slow" variety (25 km/h), you will only be traveling few km/h above the ordinary bicycle most of the time. I think that advanced leather protection does not offer very significant benefits under these conditions as the regular clothing should not wear through while skidding over ground after the fall. You should not crash much more often or heavily on E-bike.

From experience, leather gloves are nice to wear in colder weather and offer excellent protection but probably any gloves are better than bare hands. Motorbiker pants are also good on E-bike in cold and nasty weather and they also protect against dogs (most often these cannot easily bite through). Light leather jacket has a usable temperature range on E-bike but most of motorbiker jackets are very heavy.

I suggest to invest into bright colors, adequate lights and good helmet instead.